# STL: how to overload operator= for <vector>?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, operators, conversion-operator

There's simple example:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
 vector<int> veci;
 vector<double> vecd;

 for(int i = 0;i<10;++i){
  veci.push_back(i);
  vecd.push_back(i);
 }
 vecd = veci; // <- THE PROBLEM
}
```

The thing I need to know is how to overload operator = so that I could make assignment like this:

```
vector<double> = vector<int>;
```

I've just tried a lot of ways, but always compiler has been returning errors...

Is there any option to make this code work without changing it? I can write some additional lines, but can't edit or delete the existing ones. Ty.

---

OK, I see. I'll ask You in another way..
Is there any option to make this code work without changing it? I can write some additional lines, but can't edit or delete the existing ones. Ty.

Comment: If the code goes exactly like you've posted, you can simply define your own class named vector in global namespace. That would be used then. (The code wouldn't compile now because you use unqualified name of member of namespace `std` outside that namespace.)
This rather ugly hack would work even if there's `using namespace std` somewhere because of how hiding works in C++.
For exact answer, you'd have to post exact question - you'd have to define exactly what kind of edits to the code are allowed.

Answer (score 12):

Why not do it in a easier way:

```
vector<double> vecd( veci.begin(), veci.end() );
```

Or:

```
vecd.assign( veci.begin(), veci.end() );
```

Both are supported out of the box :)

Comment: @David, I know, but they're probably the most elegant solution in the STL mindset.

Comment: (I deleted the comment by mistake) I know and I agree that this is the best solution. Any other solution will end up either calling this one internally or else reimplementing the internal details of the assign.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. The assignment operator must be a member function, which means it must be a member of the std::vector template which you are not allowed to modify (or so the C++ Standard says). So instead, write  a free function:

```
void Assign( vector <double> & vd, const vector <int> & vi ) {
  // your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Interesting downvote there - I don't suppose you would care to say why?

Comment: @Kornel Thanks :-) - most of the time I ignore downvotes, but occasionally I think their is a chance that the downvoter has  a technical point they are too shy to elucidate - I suppose I should know better by now.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a puzzle, this will work...

```
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    vector<int> veci;

    {
        vector<double> vecd;
    }

    vector<int> vecd;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        veci.push_back(i);
        vecd.push_back(i);
    }

    vecd = veci; // voila! ;)
}
```